# Phaser game getting slow

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Fist time i am using phaser.io, i am repeating background and also loading other thing in update function but after few second later my game is slowing time . it look like background is not moving more. Please have a look of my code and help me in for sort out this problem. Or please give any idea to change background repeatedly without changing other thing. 
I have some code indentation problem sorry for that but please try to manage and help me.

**Game.js**

```js
var scoreTxt, score, speed, scoreTextValue, ques_label, ques_label_pizza, scoreTextKey, timerTextValue, timerTextKey, textStyle_Key, textStyle_Value, anscloud, astroid1, astroid2, astroid3, astroid4;
/*var gameType;*/ //Pizza or Noun

var bullets, quesTextValue, ansTextValue, sprite;

var fireRate = 100;
var nextFire = 0; 

var xAxis = [];
var yAxis = [];

var tempQues = [];
var tempAns = [];
var result  = []; 
var answear = [];
var ques = [];
var astroidContains = []; 
var astroidContainsText = [];  //['right', 'wrong', 'wrong', 'wrong']
var astroid, spaceShip, quesbar, diamond, randomAnsPosition;
var s1Copy;

var cloudContains = []; //['noun', 'pronoun', 'pronoun']
var QbarContainsQue = []; 

var ans,rightans;
var isAnswerCorrect = false;
var allowClick      = false;

var spaceShipXAxis = 40, loader1Width = 85, loader2Width = 70;

var bar, loader1, loader2, timer, timerSprite, timerSpriteCount = 0;
var timerCounter = 45; //timer counter will be of 45 seconds.
//var timerCounter_ = 100; //timer counter will be of 45 seconds.
var questCounter = 0; //question counter no. of question played.
var maxQuest     = 10;//max questions will be displayed is 10.

var diamondTextColor = "#8D4FA8";
var defTextColor  = "#5BEFFE";
var ansTextColor  = "#9E13DA";
var errTextColor  = '#FF0000';
var corrTextColor = '#228B22';

var corr_ans_fst;
var corr_ans_sec;
var fun_bckg, randQues;
var wrong_ans;

var barre1_x = 150;
var barre1_y = 115;
var healthValue = 100;
var x_loader = 180;
var check =0;

var setAns = [];

var setOne       = [['12+16=','28'], ['15+11=','26'], ['16+22=','38'], ['13+14=','27'], ['15+24=','39'], ['14+12=','26'], ['10+17=','27'], ['11+11=','22'],
                    ['13+15=','28'], ['12+21=','33'], ['24+13=','37'], ['33+21=','54'], ['40+18=','58'], ['34+31=','65'], ['25+42=','67'], ['22+15=','37'],
                    ['24+12=','36'], ['20+15=','35'], ['25+14=','39'], ['21+21=','42'], ['41+25=','66'], ['53+24=','77'], ['35+31=','66'], ['62+37=','99'],
                    ['54+35=','89']];

var setTwo       = [['15+18=','33'], ['17+17=','34'], ['13+19=','32'], ['18+14=','32'], ['15+27=','42'], ['18+17=','35'], ['27+29=','56'], ['23+28=','51'],
                    ['36+37=','73'], ['45+25=','70'], ['46+45=','91'], ['38+57=','95'], ['49+43=','92'], ['37+53=','90'], ['48+33=','81']];



var Game = {
    preload : function() {
        // Load the needed image for this(play) game screen.
        //load the menu screen
        this.load.image('menu', './assets/images/menu.png');

        // Here we load all the needed resources for the level.
        // background image screen
        this.load.image('playgame', './assets/images/back.png');

        // globe image screen
        this.load.image('playgame', './assets/images/back.png');
        
        // win image screen
        //this.load.image('win', './assets/images/win.png');
        // spaceship image screen
        this.load.image('spaceship', './assets/images/spaceship.png');
        // Question bar image screen
        this.load.image('quesbar', './assets/images/quesbar.png');
        // Diamond image screen
        this.load.image('diamond', './assets/images/diamond.png');
        // Astroid image screen
        this.load.image('astroid1',   'assets/images/asteroid1.png');
        this.load.image('astroid2',   'assets/images/asteroid2.png');
        this.load.image('astroid3',   'assets/images/asteroid3.png');
        this.load.image('astroid4',   'assets/images/asteroid4.png');

        // Loader image screen      
        this.load.image('loaderbck',   'assets/images/loaderbck.png');
        this.load.image('loader1',   'assets/images/loader1.png');
        this.load.image('loader2',   'assets/images/loader2.png');

        //Load the bullet
        this.load.image('bullet',   'assets/images/bullet.png');
      
    },
    create : function() {

        // By setting up global variables in the create function, we initialise them on game start.
        // We need them to be globally available so that the update function can alter them.

        textStyle_Value     = { font: "bold 20px Segoe UI", fill: defTextColor, align: "center" };
        textStyleAns    = { font: "bold 22px 'Comic Sans MS', 'Comic Sans'", fill: ansTextColor, wordWrap: true, wordWrapWidth: 10, align: "center"};
        textStyleQues    = { font: "bold 20px 'Comic Sans MS', 'Comic Sans'", fill: defTextColor, wordWrap: true, wordWrapWidth: 10, align: "center"};
            sprite = game.add.sprite(310, 485, 'spaceship');
            sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
            
        // Loading backround image
        this.playBackground();
        this.playBackground1();

        // Additional Sprites, like cloud
        this.addSprites();
        
        // Loading spaceship image
        //this.spaceship();
        // Loading questionbar image
        this.questionbar();
        // Call fun. for ques
        this.comeQus();
        // csll fun. for place astroid
       // this.astroid();
        // call fun. for Ans
        this.generateQues();
        this.generateAns();

        // Loading Diamond image
        this.diamond();
         // Start timer
        this.startTimer();
        // Set timer.
        this.setTimer();

        this.initLoader();

      
         
    },

    update: function() {


        // The update function is called constantly at a high rate (somewhere around 60fps),
        // updating the game field every time - also destroying previous objects and creating new.

        //  Our bullet group
        
        //bullets.destroy();
        sprite.destroy();

        bullets = game.add.group();
        bullets.enableBody = true;
        bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
        bullets.createMultiple(200, 'bullet', 100, false);
        bullets.setAll('anchor.x',0);
        bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 0.9);
        bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
        bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);

       
            //Repeating background..
        if(playgame != null && playgame.body.y > 600) {
            playgame.destroy();
            this.playBackground();
            
        }
        if(playgame1.body.y > 0) {
            playgame1.destroy();
            this.playBackground1();
            this.initLoader();
            
        }    
        
        if(astroid1 != undefined) astroid1.destroy();
        if(astroid2 != undefined) astroid2.destroy();
        if(astroid3 != undefined) astroid3.destroy();
        if(astroid4 != undefined) astroid4.destroy();

        this.addSprites();
        //timerTextValue.text = "00:" + timerCounter;
        this.initLoader();
        //destroing old diamond obj and creating new while change background
        //diamond.destroy();
        this.diamond();
        
        //destroing old questionbar obj and creating new while change background
        quesbar.destroy();
        this.questionbar();
        
        //Call comeQus, comeAns for show ques and ans at every background change
        // quesTextValue.destroy();
        if(quesTextValue != undefined) quesTextValue.destroy();
        this.comeQus();
        //ansTextValue.destroy();
        
        if(ansTextValue != undefined) ansTextValue.destroy();
        this.comeAns();

        if (game.input.activePointer.isDown) {
            this.fire();
        }

                allowClick = true;
            
        
    },
playBackground: function() {

       // console.log("playBackground called");
        playgame = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'playgame', 5);
        playgame.scale.set(1);
        playgame.smoothed = false;
        anim_playgame = playgame.animations.add('walk');

        anim_playgame.play(10, true);
        
        this.physics.enable(playgame, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        playgame.body.velocity.y = 50;

       
    },
    

    playBackground1: function() {

        //console.log("playBackground1 called");
        //Second background..
        playgame1 = this.add.sprite(0, -600, 'playgame', 5);
        playgame1.scale.set(1);
        playgame1.smoothed = false;
        anim_playgame1 = playgame1.animations.add('walk');

        anim_playgame1.play(10, true);
        
        this.physics.enable(playgame1, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        playgame1.body.velocity.y = 50;
    },


    questionbar: function() {
         quesbar = game.add.image(10, 530, 'quesbar');
        
    },
     diamond: function() {
         diamond = game.add.image(680, 20, 'diamond');
        
    },
   
    addSprites: function() {
       
            // loading answer cloud
            astroid1 = this.add.button(30,  90, 'astroid1', this.astroidClicked, this);
            astroid2 = this.add.button(220, 30, 'astroid2', this.astroidClicked, this);
            astroid3 = this.add.button(400, 40, 'astroid3', this.astroidClicked, this);
            astroid4 = this.add.button(600, 90, 'astroid4', this.astroidClicked, this);
        
     },

    inCorrectAnswerHit: function(index) {
        allowClick = false;
        isAnswerCorrect = false;
        
        //this.playFx('wrong_ans');
        
        for(i=0; i<=3; i++) {
            if(cloudContains[i] == "right") {
                //cloudContainsText[i].fill = corrTextColor;
                console.log("right ans hit");
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    checkAnswer: function(index) {
        // If clicked Ans is right so astroid will destroy.
        if(astroidContainsText[index] == "wrong") {
            //Here collization function will call
            
            isAnswerCorrect = true;
        }
        // If clicked word is noun (correct answer) and obstacle is redbird or blackbird - the dude will slide.
        else { 
            this.inCorrectAnswerHit(index);
        }
    },

    
    generateQues: function(){
        var que;
        // Generating random questions from given list of ques - setOne.

        s1Copy = setOne.slice();
                //var result = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {result.push(s1Copy.splice(~~(Math.random()*s1Copy.length),1)[0]);}
                s1Copy.push(...setTwo);
                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {result.push(s1Copy.splice(~~(Math.random()*s1Copy.length),1)[0]);}
                
                result.toString();
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length ; i++ ) {

                     que = result[i];
                     ques.push(que[0]);
                     ques.toString();
                     //console.log(ques);
                     answear.push(que[1]);
                    }
    },
     comeQus: function() {
                quesTextValue    = this.add.text(50,541, ques[0],textStyleQues);
                this.generateQues();
        //tempNoun    = [];
        
    },

    generateAns: function() {   

        //Generate two digitd rendom no. and create an array of ans setAns[]
       // Add digitd in array
        for(var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) { 
          var digit =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10);
          //console.log(digit);
          setAns.push(digit); 
          astroidContains[i] = "wrong";
          
        }
        console.log(astroidContains);
        //console.log(answear); 
        setAns.push(answear[0]);
        astroidContains[i] = "right";
        console.log(astroidContains);

        shuffle(setAns);

        randomAnsPosition = [0, 1, 2, 3];
        shuffle(randomAnsPosition);
    },
    
    comeAns: function() {
      
         // x and y axis param for placing Answers text.
        xAxis = [ 85, 255, 453, 675];
        yAxis = [130, 48, 60, 120];

        
        // console.log(setAns);
        // Set Answers from above array of Ans - setAns.
        for (var i = 0; i < setAns.length; i++) {
            var ans = setAns[i];
            //console.log(ans);
                   
             ansTextValue    = this.add.text(xAxis[randomAnsPosition[i]], yAxis[randomAnsPosition[i]], ans, textStyleAns); 
             astroidContainsText[i] = ansTextValue;
              
             //console.log(ansTextValue.text);
        } 
        
    },

    // Observing which cloud is clicked and checking answer accordingly.
    astroidClicked: function() {
       // alert("HEllo called");
        if(!allowClick) {
            return;
        }
        if(astroid1.game.input._x > 85 && astroid1.game.input._x < 130) {
            console.log("cloud_1_Clicked, Clicked:" + astroidContains[0]);
            this.checkAnswer(0);
        } 
        else if(astroid2.game.input._x > 255 && astroid2.game.input._x < 48) {
            //console.log("cloud_2_Clicked, Clicked:" + astroidContains[1]);
            this.checkAnswer(1);
        }
        else if(astroid3.game.input._x > 453 && astroid3.game.input._x < 60) {
            //console.log("cloud_3_Clicked, Clicked:" + astroidContains[2]);
            this.checkAnswer(2);
        }
         else if(astroid4.game.input._x > 675 && astroid4.game.input._x < 120) {
            //console.log("cloud_3_Clicked, Clicked:" + astroidContains[2]);
            this.checkAnswer(3);
        }
        allowClick = false;
    },
    
    startTimer: function() {
        //  Create our Timer
        timer = game.time.create(false);

        //  Set a TimerEvent to occur after 1 seconds
        timer.loop(1000, this.updateCounter, this);
        
        //  Set a TimerEvent to occur after 1 seconds
        //  timer.loop(100, this.timerStripeChange, this);
        
        //  Start the timer running - this is important!
        //  It won't start automatically, allowing you to hook it to button events and the like.
        timer.start();
    },
    gameOver: function() {
        
        //Gameover screen
        this.state.start('Game_Over', true, false);
    },

    initLoader: function() {

        
        //*******Loader
        check +=1; 
        var bmd = this.game.add.bitmapData(185, 30);
        bmd.ctx.beginPath();
        bmd.ctx.rect(0, 0, 185, 36);
        bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#00685e';
        bmd.ctx.fill();
    
        var bglife = this.game.add.sprite(100, 38, bmd);
        bglife.anchor.set(0.5);
        
        if(check != 0)
        bmd = this.game.add.bitmapData(x_loader-4, 26);
        else
            bmd = this.game.add.bitmapData(x_loader, 26);
            bmd.ctx.beginPath();
            bmd.ctx.rect(0, 0, 180, 26);
        
        if(x_loader <= 120 && x_loader > 60) {
            bmd.ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
        } else if(x_loader <= 60) {
            bmd.ctx.fillStyle = "#EA0B1E";
        } else {
            bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#00f910';
        }
        bmd.ctx.fill();
        
        this.widthLife = new Phaser.Rectangle(0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height);
        this.totalLife = bmd.width;
        //x_loader = ;
        /*console.log(this.totalLife);
        console.log(this.widthLife);*/
        
        this.life = this.game.add.sprite(93 - bglife.width/2 + 10, 38, bmd);
        this.life.anchor.y = 0.5;
        this.life.cropEnabled = true;
        this.life.crop(this.widthLife);
        
       // this.game.time.events.loop(1450, this.cropLife, this);
    },
    updateCounter: function() {
        if(timerCounter <= 0) {
            this.gameOver();
            return;
        }
        timerCounter--;
        
        if(this.widthLife.width <= 0){
            this.widthLife.width = this.totalLife;
          }
          else{
            //this.game.add.tween(this.widthLife).to( { width: (x_loader - 4) }, 200, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true);
            //console.log(this.widthLife.width);
            this.widthLife.width = x_loader - 4;
            x_loader = this.widthLife.width;
          }
    },

    fire: function () {

    if (game.time.now > nextFire && bullets.countDead() > 0)
    {
        nextFire = game.time.now + fireRate;

        var bullet = bullets.getFirstDead();

        bullet.reset(sprite.x - 80, sprite.y - 80);

        game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(bullet, 300);
    }

}


}


/**
 * Shuffles array in place.
 * @param {Array} a items The array containing the items.
 */
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length; i; i -= 1) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        x = a[i - 1];
        a[i - 1] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a lot of code, you should reduce it to relevant parts.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich here  i removed unnecessary code , please again look in to the code.

Comment: still too much code. and without a workign example it's hard to tell what is wrong where.

Comment: *"I have some code indentation problem sorry for that"* - Please don't be sorry, be proactive about fixing it *before* you post. (If you [edit] your question you can click "edit the above snippet" and then use the built-in "Tidy" option to fix the indenting, or use http://jspretty.com (or one of the many online JS beautifiers).)

Comment: At a guess: your game is slowing down _after some time_, so this means either of two things - a timer / event is being fired less frequently or a timescale factor is shrinking. I can see `this.initLoader()` inside something called `Update` which is a red flag to me that your game is loading itself each cycle, causing the memory usage to grow over time (you may need to profile to see what is happening). I'm not too familiar with `phaser` but that's not a bad place to start.

Comment: @XerenNarcy thanks for your response , do you have any idea about repeat background without calling it in update function.

Comment: Maybe, I can assist with the general concepts but I wouldn't be of much help with this API / library specifically. In saying that, can you please clarify what you mean by "repeat" - do you want your background to be _tessellated_, or _scrolling background seen through a viewport_, or both? In general you should only load textures and assets _once_ and on `update` calls only _move or resize_ them. If you need to switch backgrounds you should consider state-based programming for your game, and re-load (or switch visibility of) assets only on state-changes.

Comment: repeat means movable it should be running. I want to use tileSprite() but its not working.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle(or something) where we can test the game? I guess the performance decrease because of the bitmapData that you create and never destroy on every loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted it is a lot of code.
So far what I can see, is a memory leak in the update() function:

```
bullets = game.add.group();
bullets.enableBody = true;
bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
bullets.createMultiple(200, 'bullet', 100, false);
bullets.setAll('anchor.x',0);
bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 0.9);
bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
```

With that you are constantly creating new bullets. Put that in the create() function and try again.

Comment: Thank its working fine now.